# Extra Tkinter GUI popup

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've written a bunch of code that produces a GUI. Now whenever I run the code it produces the main GUI window and one additional small window with nothing in it. When I close the smaller window the large main window disappears. 
Now I've been reading other posts with similar problems, but I haven't been able to identify where the error is in my code.

Please help :)

Follow up question: How would I add a background image rather than the grey boring color?

Here is what it looks like.
[image]

```
#%% GUI Interface

import Tkinter as tk
from tkFont import Font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from Tkinter import END

#This creates the main window of an application
window = tk.Toplevel()
window.title("Sat Track")
window.geometry("1200x800")
window.configure(background='#f0f0f0')

#Imports the pictures.
pic1 = "Globeview.png"
pic2 = "MercatorView.png"
pic3 = "currentweathercroppedsmall.png"
pic4 = "GECurrentcroppedsmall.png"

#Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic1))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic2))
img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic3))
img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic4))

header = tk.Label(window, text="Satellite Control Center", font=Font(size=40))
header.pack()

toprow = tk.Frame(window)
infobox = tk.Text(toprow, width=50, height=7, font=("Calibri",12))
infobox.pack(side = "left") 
infobox.insert(END,"Current information for:"+spacer+name +'\n'+
               "Time:" +space+times+ '\n'+
               "Longitude:"+space +x_long+ '\n'+
               "Latitude:" +space+x_lat+ '\n'+     
               "Altitude:" +space+alt+space+ "[km]"+'\n'+
               "Velocity:" +space+vel+space+ "[km/s]" + '\n'+
               "Spatial Resolution: "+space +spat+space+ "[Pixels pr. m]"
               )
toprow.pack()

midrow = tk.Frame(window)
globeview = tk.Label(midrow, image = img1)
globeview.pack(side = "left") # the side argument sets this to pack in a row rather than a column
mercatorview = tk.Label(midrow, image = img2)
mercatorview.pack(side = "left")
midrow.pack() # pack the toprow frame into the window 

bottomrow = tk.Frame(window)
currentweather= tk.Label(bottomrow, image = img3)
currentweather.pack(side = "left")
gearth = tk.Label(bottomrow, image = img4)
gearth.pack(side = "left")
bottomrow.pack()

#Start the GUI
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Toplevel` from `window = tk.Toplevel()`. I don't have a python2 dist available -- I'm on python3 but when I removed `TopLevel` from my code, it only brought up one window. So, the python3 way is....

```
import tkinter as tk

#This creates the main window of an application
window = tk.Tk()



#Start the GUI
window.mainloop()
```

I think the only difference would be that python2's tkinter is actually Tkinter (as you have already done).

Comment: if I remove it, I get an error saying the module is not callable.
Yeah I'm forced to use python2 on this task, although I mostly use 3. Its a huge pain in the ass using tkinter on py2 imo.

Comment: Yeah, it's because of how you imported it. If you do 'import Tkinter as tk' and then do 'window = tk.Tk()' will it work?

Comment: Also, I've edited my answer so that my import more-closely reflects yours (with the exception of capitalization).     Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Changing window =tk.Toplevel() to tk.Tk() did the job. Thank you =)

Answer (score 7):

Every tkinter application needs exactly one instance of `Tk` class. In your code you don't create one but <strike>`mainloop` seem to create one automatically</strike> it's still created (See [Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)'s comment below), even though you can't(easily) refer to it later.

If you will use additional `Toplevel` widgets to that of your curent one go:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw() # You can go root.iconify(), root.deiconify() later if you
                # want to make this window visible again at some point.
# MAIN CODE HERE
root.mainloop()
```

if not simply replace:

```
window = tk.Toplevel()
```

with:

```
window = tk.Tk()
```

Note: Also note that if you're working using IDLE keep in mind that it creates its own `Tk` object which may hide the fact that your application will need one when used standalone.

Comment: It's not `mainloop` that creates the root window. The first time you create a widget, a root window will be created if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I credited the other one though, as he was first :p But you both got to the same conclusion. Thank you =)