# Why is Toplevel showing 2 windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am trying to make a tkinter application which doesn't close everything (other windows) when the first window (root) is closed. I have tried to use `Toplevel()` which works perfectly for pop-up windows in other programs but not for making a base level.

```
from tkinter import *

top = Toplevel(bg='red')

top.mainloop()
```

I don't know if this is possible or I don't know if I can change the `Tk()`'s properties to make it so it doesn't shut all other windows down.

Comment: You don't use a Toplevel as root only Tk. Toplevel is not a root, but always a 'dialog' for a root window (Tk).

Comment: to create main window use `Tk()`. `Toplevel()` is used to create second window (subwindow/dialog/messagebox/etc.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47799765/7032856

Comment: You simply must have a root window. If you don't create one, tkinter will create one for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two windows getting displayed because when a tkinter widget is created, it forces a `Tk` instance to be created as well, and every widget, unless a parent is explicitly passed, is a child to that automatically created `Tk` instance. So your code essentially mimics the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

top = Toplevel(root, bg='red')

root.mainloop()
```

Now there are some ways to work around that for the behavior you want, one is to hide the actual `Tk` instance:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

top = tk.Toplevel(root, bg='red')

#to display root window again
#root.iconify()
#root.deiconify()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Another way would be to overrule the deletion of the `root` itself, but I doubt that's actually what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk


def callback():
    print("Won't close")

root = tk.Tk()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Withdrawing the root works as I would like, thanks a lot