# Turtle in Tkinter creating multiple windows

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am attempting to create a quick turtle display using Tkinter, but some odd things are happening.

First two turtle windows are being created, (one blank, one with the turtles), secondly, any attempt of turning the tracer off is not working.

This might be a simple fix but at the moment I cannot find it.

Any help would be appreciated,

Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Top 10\'s')

def loadingscreen():

    canvas = tk.Canvas(master = window, width = 500, height = 500)
    canvas.pack()

    arc1 = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
    arc2 = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)


    #clean up the turtles and release the window
    def cleanup():
        turtle.tracer(True)
        arc1.ht()
        arc2.ht()
        turtle.done()

    #animate the turtles
    def moveTurtles(rangevar,radius,extent,decrease):
        for distance in range(rangevar):
           arc1.circle(-radius,extent = extent)
           arc2.circle(-radius,extent = extent)
           radius -= decrease

    #Set the turtle
    def setTurtle(turt,x,y,heading,pensize,color):
       turt.pu()
       turt.goto(x,y)
       turt.pd()
       turt.seth(heading)
       turt.pensize(pensize)
       turt.pencolor(color)

    #draw on the canvas
    def draw():
        #set variables
        rangevar = 200
        radius = 200
        decrease = 1
        extent = 2

        #setup and draw the outline
        turtle.tracer(False)
        setTurtle(arc1,0,200,0,40,'grey')
        setTurtle(arc2,14,-165,180,40,'grey')
        moveTurtles(rangevar,radius,extent,decrease)

        #setup and animate the logo 
        turtle.tracer(True)
        setTurtle(arc1,0,200,0,20,'black')
        setTurtle(arc2,14,-165,180,20,'black')
        moveTurtles(rangevar,radius,extent,decrease)

    #main program
    def main():
        turtle.tracer(False)
        arc1.speed(0)
        arc2.speed(0)
        draw()
        cleanup()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
            main()
        except:
            print("An error occurred!!")



loadingscreen()
```

Essentially I am creating a Tk window, then a canvas, then two turtles, and then animating these turtles

Comment: Have you tried commenting out various parts of your code in order to pinpoint the double window problem? That might help you spot the problem.

Comment: Okay, so the tracer(False)'s were creating the double window, so how do I now set tracer to false?

Comment: Does `turtle.tracer()` work for you?

Comment: That creates the second window though, and doesn't set the tracer for the drawing to false

Comment: What about `turtle.Screen().tracer()`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're trying to call turtle screen methods without actually having a turtle screen.  When turtle is embedded in tkinter like this, you can overlay a `Canvas` with a `TurtleScreen` instance which will provide some, but not all, of the screen features of the standalone turtle:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

def cleanup():
    """ hide the turtles """

    arc1.hideturtle()
    arc2.hideturtle()

def moveTurtles(rangevar, radius, extent, decrease):
    """ animate the turtles """

    for _ in range(rangevar):
        arc1.circle(-radius, extent=extent)
        arc2.circle(-radius, extent=extent)
        radius -= decrease

def setTurtle(turtle, x, y, heading, pensize, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.setheading(heading)
    turtle.pensize(pensize)
    turtle.pencolor(color)

def draw():
    # set variables
    rangevar = 200
    radius = 200
    decrease = 1
    extent = 2

    screen.tracer(False)  # turn off animation while drawing outline

    # setup and draw the outline
    setTurtle(arc1, 0, 200, 0, 40, 'grey')
    setTurtle(arc2, 14, -165, 180, 40, 'grey')
    moveTurtles(rangevar, radius, extent, decrease)

    screen.tracer(True)  # turn animation back on for the following

    # setup and animate the logo
    setTurtle(arc1, 0, 200, 0, 20, 'black')
    setTurtle(arc2, 14, -165, 180, 20, 'black')
    moveTurtles(rangevar, radius, extent, decrease)

# main program

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Top 10's")

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)

arc1 = RawTurtle(screen)
arc1.speed('fastest')

arc2 = RawTurtle(screen)
arc2.speed('fastest')

draw()
cleanup()
```

Another suggestion: don't mess with `tracer()` until after everything else is working and then (re)read it's documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the answer for the two windows that are being created: the one with the turtles is obvious, and the blank one is for the main root window that you define (`window = tk.Tk()`). If you want it not to appear at all, you can add the following line right after its definition:

`window.withdraw()`

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289343/7009806) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1407700/7009806).