# Python Turtle not in Tkinter Canvas & Button not in Corner

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I am working on creating a game with turtle in Tkinter's Canvas Module. I have run into a problem where when I try and spawn a new turtle it spawns in a new window instead of the canvas. What have I done wrong? I would also like to resolve my issue with the quit button. I have been trying to place it in the bottom right corner. I have tried `.place()` and `.grid()` but without success. I have also tried other solutions on stackoverflow but they either result in an error or just disappear, probably behind the canvas.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import turtle
import time
import sys

def spawn(e=None):
    xrand = random.randint(0,500)
    yrand = random.randint(0,500)
    turtle.RawTurtle(app)
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x=xrand,y=yrand)

def systemap(e=None):
    app.pack()
    button.pack()

def f(e=None):
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(1)

def l(e=None):
    t.setheading(180)
    t.forward(1)

def r(e=None):
    t.setheading(0)
    t.forward(1)

def b(e=None):
    t.setheading(270)
    t.forward(1)

def quit(e=None):
    time.sleep(1)
    window.destroy()
    sys.exit()

window = tk.Tk()
#window.iconbitmap('py.ico')
window.title("Turtle Graphics")
window.geometry("750x500")
window.resizable(False, False)

button = tk.Button(window, text="Exit", command = quit)

app = tk.Canvas(master=window, width=500, height=500, bg="white")

t=turtle.RawTurtle(app)

window.bind("<Up>", f)
window.bind("<Left>", l)
window.bind("<Right>", r)
window.bind("<Down>", b)

window.bind("<w>", f)
window.bind("<a>", l)
window.bind("<d>", r)
window.bind("<s>", b)

window.bind("<e>", spawn)

window.bind("<Escape>", quit)

systemap()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"the quit button ... to place it in the bottom right corner"***: Your window,have the same size `.geometry(...x500")` as `.Canvas(..., height=500` and you didn't allow to grow `.resizable(False, False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [turtle-in-tkinter-creating-multiple-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452857/turtle-in-tkinter-creating-multiple-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you have to use either the `.pack()` or `.grid()` on everything that is going in the window otherwise it will not work so you could not have a button using the `.pack()` then some text using `.grid()`. So you could get away with using the .place on all the things that need to go in the window to put them where you need so it would be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import turtle
import time
import sys

def systemap(e=None):
    app.place(x=100,y=-4)
    button.place(x=720,y=475)

def f(e=None):
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(1)

def l(e=None):
    t.setheading(180)
    t.forward(1)

def r(e=None):
    t.setheading(0)
    t.forward(1)

def b(e=None):
    t.setheading(270)
    t.forward(1)

def quit(e=None):
    time.sleep(1)
    window.destroy()
    sys.exit()

window = tk.Tk()
window.iconbitmap('py.ico')
window.title("Turtle Graphics")
window.geometry("750x500")
window.resizable(False, False)

button = tk.Button(window, text="Exit", command = quit)

app = tk.Canvas(master=window, width=500, height=500, bg="white")

t=turtle.RawTurtle(app)

window.bind("<Up>", f)
window.bind("<Left>", l)
window.bind("<Right>", r)
window.bind("<Down>", b)

window.bind("<w>", f)
window.bind("<a>", l)
window.bind("<d>", r)
window.bind("<s>", b)

window.bind("<Escape>", quit)

systemap()

window.mainloop()
```